# How to close my navbar when I click on one of the sections?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

I have a responsive navbar who does everything well except one thing... I would like to close my navbar when I click on one of the sections (ex:about, services, ...). I can only close it with a hamburger button at the moment. For resume, it's scrolling well but my navbar hides the page (does not close).

Css code:

```
is-open .header__navbar--menu {
    transform: translateY(0);
}
     /*---head responsive medium screen---*/


@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .header__navbar--toggle {
        display: flex;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .header__navbar--menu {
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #f39c12;
        top: 0;left: 0;
    }
    .header__navbar--menu-link {
        margin: 20px 0;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    .header__navbar--menu-link:hover {
        color: black;
    }
} 

    /*---head responsive small screen---*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px){
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .main_title {
        font-size: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .main_title-btn {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 10px 14px;
    }

    .header__navbar--toggle {
        width: 25px;
        height: 45px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .header__navbar--menu-link:hover {
        color: #333;
    }
}
```

Js code(tp open but not to close):

```
/*slide toggle*/
$('.header__navbar--toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.header__navbar').toggleClass('is-open');
})
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body')
        .stop()
        .animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top},1000);
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trigger a click event, or toggle the 'is-open' class of the hamburger menu in your event listener:

```
$('.header__navbar--toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.header__navbar').toggleClass('is-open');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
      //use this:
      //$(‘.header__navbar').toggleClass('is-open');
      // OR this:
      //$(‘.header__navbar--toggle').click()
      // OR this:
      //$(‘.header__navbar’).removeClass(‘is-open');
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body')
        .stop()
        .animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top},1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i m a beginner html/css(I don't still use js) and when i use this code i have an error with the synthax...

Comment: It is the same code, except the commented out part, and the added semicolon. Please try adding  $(‘.header__navbar’).removeClass(‘is-open');  after the  evt.preventDefault();  line, in your own code.

Comment: It was me who made a mistake.Its work great!Thank you for your time!